# Travel within the Schengen area with Fiktionbescheinigung

Tags: schengen, germany, europe, italy, long-stay-visas

I have a Namibian passport and I'm currently working in Germany with a National long-stay D visa which will expire early May. My appointment at the Auslanderbehorde for the residence permit card is on the 29th of March.

I want to travel to Italy in mid-May, by then my visa will be expired. I know I will get a Fiktionbescheinigung at the Auslanderbehorde, but I'm not sure which type. As a Namibian, I would usually need a Schengen visa to travel to EU countries, but I know my D visa entitles me to travel within the Schengen area, so will this be possible when I only have the Fiktionbescheinigung?

I'm pretty sure my permit card will not be ready by my intended travel date considering the pandemic and Ukrainian refugee crisis which I've heard is placing a bit of strain on the Auslanderbehorde in Leipzig.

EDIT: Whether or not I can travel seems to depend on whether I get my Fiktionbeschenigung based on paragraph 3 or 4 of [Section 81](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1732). My interpretation is that I will get it based on (4):

> (4) If a foreigner applies for an extension of his or her residence
> title or for a different residence title before his or her current
> residence title expires, the current residence title is deemed to
> remain in force from the time it expires until the time of the
> decision by the foreigners authority. This does not apply to visas
> issued in accordance with section 6 (1).

Because I am indeed a *foreigner* applying for a *different* residence title *before my current* (national long-stay D visa) *residence title expires*. Nowe we can arque about what "residence title" means and whether my D visa qualifies as one which seems to be the point of contention here, since everyone seems to believe that my residence permit application counts as a "first time" application. According to [this](https://www.bamf.de/SharedDocs/Anlagen/EN/EMN/Studien/wp67-emn-wechsel-aufenthaltstiteln-aufenthaltszwecken.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=17) document issued by BAMF:

> The five types of residence titles are as follows: a visa, a residence
> permit, a settlement  permit,  an  EU  long-term  residence  permit
> and  an  EU  Blue  Card

Therefore, though I am a first time applicant for a residence *permit*, I am not a first_time applicant for a residence *title*. My conviction on this matter is further bolstered by the fact that later in paragraph for they go out of their way to specify that:

> This does not apply to visas issued in accordance with section 6 (1)

Section 6 (1) being for Schengen visas and transit visas. My visa being of course based on paragraph (3) of Section 6, not the exception (1), you could see why I would think this *does* apply to me.

So, can anyone tell me where my logic goes wrong? None of the information that is valid for a US citizen is valid for me so I cannot refer to those previous posts and existing questions as I simply do not think they are relevant to my case, as no US citizen had to go through the D visa application.

Comment: A **Fiktionsbescheinigung** is not valid for travel to other Schengen Countries when it contains the text **Gilt nicht für Auslandsreisen**. This will be the case for persons who require a Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area and are not renewing their residence permit. So you must check and see if the Fiktionsbescheinigung contains this text or not.

Comment: @MarkJohnson could someone in this situation reasonably expect to receive a visa through the Italian consulate in Germany?  If so, would the trip outside Germany pose a risk to the pending application?  If you know the answers to these questions, perhaps you should post an answer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson "This will be the case for persons who require a Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area and are not renewing their residence permit" - by residence permit, do you mean an existing residence permit card, and not the long-stay national visa that I currently have?

Comment: A residence permit must exist. Schengen Border Code: Article 2 (Definitions) 16. ‘residence permit’ **excludes** in (b)(i) 'temporary permits issued **pending examination of a first application for a residence permit**'.

Comment: For persons who do not require a visa, can travel with their Fiktionsbescheinigung and passport, with the Fiktionsbescheinigung serving as an replacement for the (possibly outdated) entry stamp.

Comment: @phoog A Schengen Visa is not listed in the exceptions of the regulation: [Traveling with Erlaubnisfiktion [Fiktionsbescheinigung] - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169855/95267)

Comment: @Mark Johnson None of these linked posts seem relevant to me, I did read most of them prior to submitting my own question. I believe my situation is different to that of a US citizen who can go to any Schengen state visa-free and then apply for residence from here. I had to jump through a lot of hoops to get my national long-stay D visa before I was allowed to enter. Please see the edited version of my Q. Interpretation of bureaucratic jargon is not my forte, so feel free to offer a rebuttal to my reading of the rules as applying to my personal case, NOT being a US citizen.

Comment: You do not have a residence title. When the national long-stay D visa expires, you will be issued a Fiktionbeschenigung based on §81(3) (*If a foreigner who is legally resident in the federal territory and does not possess a residence title ...*). For the Schengen Border Code, this is not considered a residence permit that allows you to travel to other Schengen countries.

Comment: Since your citizenship requires a visa to enter the Schengen Area, this Fiktionbeschenigung will be stamped with **Gilt nicht für Auslandsreisen**, since you are **not** eligible to enter the Schengen Area **solely** based on your passport and since the Fiktionsbescheinigung is not considered to be a residence permit..

Comment: As to the question, from @phoog, about the Italian consulate in Germany issuing a Schengen Visa: there is nothing in the regulation that states that it would 'pose a risk to the pending application'. §81(3) allows you to stay in Germany 'up to the time of the decision by the foreigners authority.' and the visa would allow you to enter the Schengen Area outside of Germany (as did the expired national long-stay D visa). This case is not covered in the regulation.

Comment: @Sone You might be right and I have retracted my close vote. I was pretty sure that a national visa didn't count as a residence title when determining wether your fictional certificate will be issued based on paragraph 3 or 4 of section 81, but what you are quoting seem to indicate that I am wrong. If you get a fictional certificate based on paragraph 4, it counts as a fullworthy temporary extension of the rights you had based on the national visa and you can use it for travel to Italy. The 'value' of the fictional certificates does not depend on wether you otherwise need a visa or not.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo In any case, I have bought the tickets to Italy. So whether I will be able to use them I will see in a week when I return from the Auslanderbehorde. I will then update this post with whether my fictional certificate was issued according to paragraph (3) or (4), as I think this information might be useful to people in a similar scenario. Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also think your conclusion is correct.

You should then receive a Fiktionsbescheinigung based on § 81(4), since the text below (81.4.0) explicitly includes a national visa where the issuance requirements for a residence permit have already been determined (6.4.1).

> **81.4.0** General Administrative Provisions for the Residence Act (page 335)
> In [§ 81] Absatz 4 wird eine Sonderregelung für die Fälle getroffen, in denen der Betroffene bereits einen Aufenthaltstitel besitzt. **Hiervon erfasst sind auch Fälle, in denen der Betroffene ein nationales Visum besitzt**.
>
> > [§ 81] Paragraph 4 contains a special regulation for cases in which the person concerned already has a residence permit. **This also includes cases in which the person concerned has a national visa**.

> **6.4.1** (page 57)
> ...
> Nach § 4 Absatz 1 Satz 2 Nummer 1 ist das nationale Visum ein eigenständiger **Aufenthaltstitel**. Seine Erteilung richtet sich gemäß § 6 Absatz 4 Satz 2
> nach den für die Aufenthalts- und Niederlassungserlaubnis sowie die Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt-EG je nach Aufenthaltszweck geltenden Vorschriften. Bereits für die Erteilung des Visums **müssen daher neben den allgemeinen Regelerteilungsvoraussetzung** gemäß ... erforderlichen besonderen tatbestandlichen Erfordernisse **erfüllt sein**.
> Vor Ablauf der Geltungsdauer des Visums ist entsprechend dem bei der Visumerteilung angegebenen Aufenthaltszweck eine **Aufenthaltserlaubnis**, Niederlassungserlaubnis oder Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt-EG im Inland **zu beantragen**.
>
> > According to § 4 paragraph 1 sentence 2 number 1, the national visa is an independent **residence title**. Its issuance is based on Section 6 Paragraph 4 Clause 2 according to the regulations applicable to the residence and settlement permit as well as the EC long-term residence permit, depending on the purpose of the stay.  For the issuance of the visa, therefore, in **addition to the general standard issuance requirements must be met** according to ... necessary special factual requirements.
> > Before the validity of the visa expires, a **residence permit**, settlement permit or permit for long-term EC residence in Germany **must be applied for**, depending on the purpose of the stay stated when the visa was issued.
> > ...