# Re-entry intro Germany as American without visa but with working contract

Tags: visas, usa, germany, eu

My US-citizen partner has been working in Germany for the last 3 years. She has been working in an intragovernmental organization and as such did not receive a 'proper' German visa but instead was issued a [Sonderausweis](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/de/DEU-HD-01003/index.html). Since a few weeks ago, she no longer works at this organization (and she had to turn in her Sonderausweis as a result) but instead is expected to start working at a regular German employer (she's a scientist and will work at a scientific institute). Her contract is in the process of being set up and she will sign it within a few days. Once she has the contract she will apply for a [Blue Card](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/buergerservice/faq/02a-what-is-the-blue-card/606754), which she is expected to get, but it will take 4-8 weeks. Right now **she has no visa for Germany or the Schengen area.**

We planned a trip to the US at the beginning of October and we are starting to get worried about re-entry into Germany. Most probably the Blue Card application will not have gone through by then. Will this be an issue? Can she simply re-enter Germany without a visa under the rule that Americans are allowed to stay in the Schengen area for 3 months? Is there something we need/can do to make re-entry possible? Does bringing proof of residency/work contract make any sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Once she has the contract she will apply for a Blue Card, which she is expected to get but it will take 4-8 weeks.
> We planned a trip to the US at the beginning of October...

While making the **residence permit** application, inform them of this intended trip.

For this, a [Fiktionsbescheinigung](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326233/en/) will be issued which will prove that an application for a residence permit has been made.

Since she does not require a visa for the entry into the Schengen Area, the Fiktionsbescheinigung will show that she is returning to take up residence in Germany.

---

**Sources**:

- [Fiktionsbescheinigung (Fictional Certificate) - Services - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326233/en/)
- [Traveling with Erlaubnisfiktion - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169855/95267)

Comment: Thank you for the answer - perhaps I wasn't clear but she is currently a resident in Germany already (she has been for the last 3 years). Does having a valid residency solve our issue?

Comment: This will probably be treated as a renewal due to the previous Sonderausweis. A Fiktionsbescheinigung can also be issued for a renewal if the application is done before the previous one has expired. In this case it doesn't matter since she is eligable to apply for an initial residence permit from inside Germany.

Comment: "If the male or female applicant is lawfully resident without a visa in the Federal Republic, because he or she is entitled to be by virtue of his/her nationality, the fictional certificate will be issued in accordance with § 81 Section 3 of the Residence Act.
This permits residence in the area of the Federal Republic until a decision has been made regarding the application. This fictional certification, however, does not permit re-entry into the territory of the Federal Republic."  Is this not cause for concern?

Comment: @phoog No, since the *General Administrative Provisions for the Residence Act* 81.3.6 states *Regulations according to which **entry without a residence permit is permitted for other reasons ... remain untouched.*** See answer to [Traveling with Erlaubnisfiktion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169855/95267) where the full text can be read.

Comment: It’s worth noting that many German *Ausländerbehörde* are so backed up that the timely issue of a Fiktionsbescheinigung may not be realistic possibility.

Comment: One last follow-up question: I've read that the re-entry into Germany without a visum for us-americans is only possible for 90 days within any 180 days window. Since she has spent the last 3 years in Germany, won't this be apparent from her passport stamps?

Comment: @PejoPhylo As a **visitor** yes, but not as a **resident**. The time in the country that issued the residence permit does not count. With a Fiktionsbescheinigung, the status will be that of a resident.

Comment: @PejoPhylo No idea how they would check that previously a *Sonderausweis* existed. For the planned *Entry/Exit System (EES)* system they would check the residence permit database, but I have no idea if that is already in place.

Comment: "Fiktionsbescheinigung (Fictional Certificate)" and "Erlaubnisfiktion (fictional permission)" looks like horrible phrasing for something official.  What is to stop anybody unofficially offering these and excusing themselves by saying "it says FICTION in big letters at the top"

Comment: @Henry 'Erlaubnisfiktion' was the term used by the OP of that question. 'Fiktion' (as in latin 'fictio', where it comes from) has a double meaning: fiction or **assumption**. In this context  a Fiktionsbescheinigung means 'Certifies that, until a final decision has been made, it is **assumed** that the application will be granted.' Feel free of offer a two word english term that expresses that thought.

Comment: @MarkJohnson - I was not complaining about your usage or the OP's, but more the German authorities.  We have "legal fiction" in English, but do not print it on forms.

Comment: @Henry I really can't say why this term is now being used. In the past *Temporary residence permit* (Vorläufige Aufenthaltserlaubnis) was used.

Answer (score 2):

According to the German Mission in the United States, "Citizens of the United States of America may also apply for their residence permit after entering Germany without a Visa." So, you and your partner can return to Germany and apply on arrival at the Ausländerbehörde.

I cannot comment from experience if this will be faster, but it might make more sense rather than applying outside of Germany if you are already residents. However it's important to mention that until you have received confirmation from the Ausländerbehörde, (e.g., your partner receives their Aufenhaltstitel) your partner cannot begin working.

Sources:

- [Residence Visa/Long Stay Visa - German Mission in the United States](https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/visa/residence-visa/922288?openAccordionId=item-2435482-2-panel)
- [The EU Blue Card - Federal Office for Migration and Refugees](https://www.bamf.de/EN/Themen/MigrationAufenthalt/ZuwandererDrittstaaten/Migrathek/BlaueKarteEU/blauekarteeu-node.html)

Comment: It should be noted that for German **national visas**, where the goal is to take up residence, the decision about the visa is made by the responsible authority inside Germany. So if you apply in New York or locally, the same team will be processing the application.