Traveling Outside Germany: Impact on Residence Permit Processing?
I am a non-EU citizen who recently moved to Germany and applied for a residence permit. Currently, I have a Fiktionsbescheinigung issued under Section 81(3), which does not allow me to re-enter Germany if I leave. However, my 90-day Schengen visa-free period is still valid.
I have a 7-day conference outside the EU, where my paper has been accepted, and I must attend. I plan to re-enter Germany using my remaining visa-free days under the 90-day rule.
Will leaving Germany and re-entering using the visa-free allowance create problems or delays in the ongoing residence permit application process?

This is a very good question, but maybe you should also ask it to the immigration authority in germany. Also, you may get some high quality answers at Expatriates SE.

Having a Fiktionsbescheinigung does not invalidate any other rights you might have to enter or stay in Germany or any other Schengen country for that matter. If you are sure that you haven't exceeded the 90 days visa free allowance (the time you have spent in Germany with a Fiktionsbescheinigung while waiting for your residence permit do count towards these 90 days), you may without problems leave and later reenter as any other visa-free visitor.
When reentering the Schengen area, the border police or immigration inspector will probably not even be aware of your Fiktionsbescheinigung and treat you as any other visa-free visitor.

I really don't know about the situation in Germany, but doesn't exiting the country (officially) have an influence on the residence permit application (at least in some cases)? I.e. yes, you can re-enter using the visa-free process, but doesn't leaving the country invalidate/cancel the application? I think this is supposed to be the case for some types of permits in some countries, no idea about OP's specific situation.

@jcaron Refugees may in Germany have a legal status causing them to loose their right to stay if they leave Germany. There are however no such restrictions for applicants for 'regular' residence permits.

-1 Permission to stay under national law do not count for the visitor Schengen days while inside the country that issued that permission.

@MarkJohnson It does if you are staying while waiting for your initial residence permit. A Fiktionsbescheinigung issued based on 81(3) does not count as a full-worthy national visa or residence permit.

Kindly quote a source that states that explicitly.

The Fiktionsbescheinigung itsself, for initial applications, is not a visa replacement - but does allow you to remain in Germany. The Schengen visitor rule no longer applies while within Germany. But a person who has a c-visa already (or does not require a visa, only their passport) can travel with that visa or passport, where outside of Germany the Schengen rules again applies.

@MarkJohnson That is explitely stated in the Schengen Border Code as already pointed out in the very similar question where your attempt to answer has several down votes: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169851/traveling-with-erlaubnisfiktion
